# $X$ a metric space, proof that every infinite subset of $X$ has a limit point in $X$ given subsequence convergence

Tags: general-topology, proof-writing, solution-verification

Let $X$ be a metric space.

> Assertion: Every sequence in $X$ has a subsequence that converges to a point of $X$.

Give the above Assertion, proof the following statement:

> Every infinite subset of $X$ has a limit point in $X$.

**Proof:** Let $A\subset X$ be an infinite subset. Choose a sequence $(x_n)_{n=1}^\infty$ such that $x_n\in X$ for all $n$. Then by the Assertion, $(x_n)$ has a subsequence with a limit $x$ in $X$. This implies that $A$ has a limit point and thus the statement is proven.

*Questions:* Is this proof correct? I know that this is part of a Theorem about compact spaces and I need to prove this specific implication.

It is said that this implication can be proven such that it is valid in any topological space. Does the proof presented fulfills this? How can this be possible since $X$ is a metric space and thus it is implied that the topology of $X$ is the one induced by the metric?

Answer (score 1):

Your proof is not sufficient. You need to prove that any neighborhood of the limit $x$ contains at least one point of $X$ **distinct** of $x$.

And for that the hypothesis that $X$ is infinite is crucial.

Comment: Could it be complete if I add, let $V$ be a neighborhood of $x$ and let $\epsilon>0$, since $x_{n_k}\rightarrow x$, $x_{n_k}\in B_{1/n}(x)\subset V$ for some $1/n < \epsilon$. Thus, every neighborhood of $x$ contains an element of $A$, thus proving that $A$ has a limit point.

Comment: No, that won’t be enough. You need to get rid of the case where the subsequence is eventually constant and equal to the limit. And for that you have to use that $X$ is infinite.

Answer (score 1):

Choosing a sequence in $X$ clearly won’t help you show that the set $A$ has a limit point: for that you need to choose a sequence in $A$. And you can’t choose just any old sequence: if $X=\Bbb R$, and $A=\{0\}\cup[1,2]$, the constant sequence $\langle 0,0,0,\ldots\rangle$ is a sequence in $A$ that converges to $0$, but $0$ is not a limit point of $A$, because $(-1,1)$ is an open nbhd of $0$ that contains no point of $A$ except $0$ itself.

You need to use the hypothesis that $A$ is infinite and start with a sequence $\langle x_n:n\in\Bbb N\rangle$ such that each $x_n\in A$, and $x_n\ne x_m$ whenever $n\ne m$, so that the points of the sequences are all distinct. **Now** use the hypothesis that this sequence has a subsequence converging to some $p\in X$ to show that $p$ must be a limit point of $A$.

Comment: If I assume, as you said, that every term in $(x_n)$ is different (so that we can get rid of isolated points), then would this complete the answer (also in a further response below): let $V$ be a neighborhood of $x$ and let $\epsilon >0$. Since $x_{n_k}\rightarrow x$, $x_{n_k}\in B_{1/n}(x)\subset V$ for some $1/n < \epsilon$. Thus every neighborhood of $x$ contains an element of $A$, proving that $A$ has a limit point $x$?

Comment: @user2820579: It needs a little more work: you need to show that $V$ contains at least one point of $A\setminus\{x\}$, not just of $A$. You could, for instance, observe that at most one point of the convergent subsequence can be equal to $x$, so you can replace the subsequence with a tail of it that does not contain $x$. Now any $x_{n_k}$ that you use is guaranteed to be in $A\setminus\{x\}$.